# how to turn on Touch pad disable or enable double tap led?

Tags: touchpad, multi-touch, synaptics, patch

I have a synaptic touch pad with a led in right corner, and in Windows when I tap two times on led it starts blinking and touch pad turns off.

On Google I found many posts on this, also [this](http://abhinandh.tumblr.com/post/4336662463/getting-the-double-tap-on-the-led-to-disable-touchpad) but I don't known what I must do with these files can anyone write some instructions for me?

PS. Im using a Ubuntu Gnome 14.04

Sorry for my bad English

Comment: have you solved it? i have posted a duplicate [here](http://askubuntu.com/q/538570/47206) to get more attention. the link you posted seems old and not ubuntu related). if still want an answer post more detail on your laptop model